# How to pause background music when youtube video is played

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using HTML5 audio tag to play some background music,there's also a YouTube video on the page. I can't figure out how to stop background music automatically when the YouTube video is played.

```
<audio id="player" autoplay src="War drums.mp3"></audio>
    <div id="music">
<button id="play" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"></button>
<button id="pause" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()"></button>
<button id="up" onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume+=0.1"></button>
<button id="down" onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume-=0.1"></button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out the [YouTube JavaScript Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like :

```
var youtubeplayer = document.getElementById('youtubeid');

youtubeplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(e) {

   if (e === 1) {
       document.getElementById('player').pause();
   } else {
       document.getElementById('player').play();
   };

});
```

I'd give the API reference a good read before using it though.